# How to examine query results in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am running a query using the Elasticsearch filter plugin in Logstash. I can't find any documentation on how to examine the results of the query so that I can send out alerts based on the results. I'm aware that Kibana Alerting is a better approach, but the observability functionalities of ELK haven't yet been enabled for my company's nodes. Here is my current input, if needed:

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        id => "es_input_plugin"
        user => "myuser"
        password => "mypassword"
        hosts => "myhost"
        ca_file => "C:\devsetup\logstash-8.6.0\rootca3.crt"
        ssl => true
        index => "log-com-ms-icm--*"
        query => '{ 
                    "query": {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "now-1d/d"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "size": 1
                }'
        docinfo => true
        docinfo_target => "[@metadata][doc]"
        schedule => "0 * * * *"
    }
}
```

My goal is just to check that there is at least one record posted within the last day, and send out an alert if that isn't the case. Kibana alerting would make this much easier and I've requested that it be enabled, but who knows how long that could take. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following output so you can inspect the event content

```
output {
   stdout {
      codec => json
   }
}
```

Another solution is to use [Logshark utility](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dec-13th-2022-en-debugging-logstash-and-filebeat-pipelines-with-logshark/319308) which allows you to debug Logstash pipelines.

Comment: I have this enabled, but can I automatically inspect this to check for records within logstash? If so then how to I go about doing so, this is the step I can't find any documentation for. It may be something that should be obvious, but I have never used this stack before.

Comment: No you cannot inspect in-flight documents as they go through the pipeline unfortunately. Logshark is the closest to what you're looking for

Comment: Appreciate the response. I ended up just using a shell script instead of trying to do everything within logstash.